# coq: Tactic to replace true hypothesis in 'and' statement

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

```
Assumptions:
l: a < d

Goal: (s a /\ a < d) <-> s a
```

Here, I have an `/\` with an assumed statement. The goal just needs l to be applied, but I cant seem to figure out the tactic. Apply, rewrite, and replace don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out -- you just have to run `propositional`, which will evaluate such tautological logic automatically.

Answer (score 0):

`rewrite` would only work if `a < d` was a notation for an equality or an equivalence relation, but here I assume that is not the case.

[`tauto`](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/proofs/automatic-tactics/logic.html#coq:tacn.tauto) automatically solves your goal, as does [`easy`](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/proofs/automatic-tactics/auto.html#coq:tacn.easy), but I think you were asking for something less automatic.

It's a bit disappointing, but the best non-automatic proof I can come up with is to split your goal:

```
Goal forall a d s, a < d -> (s a /\ a < d) <-> s a.
Proof.
  intros a d s l.
  split.
  - intros [sa _].
    exact sa.
  - intros sa.
    split.
    + exact sa.
    + exact l.
Qed.
```

If you're interested in using `rewrite` for this kind of thing, the [MathComp](https://math-comp.github.io/) library defines things in ways that make `rewrite` the most useful tactic, and in particular it would work in a translated version of your goal. But probably the best short-term solution here is to make use of some automation tactics.

Answer (score 0):

Using SSReflect/mathcomp, as mentioned by @ana-borges, one can indeed `rewrite` the Assumption `l` (which is what `->` does); this can then be followed by a `split`, with a `true` in the conjunction.

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.

Goal forall a d s, a < d -> (s a /\ a < d) <-> s a.
Proof. move=> a d s ->; split=> [[sa _] //|sa]; exact: conj. Qed.
```

Maybe there is another shorter version, though.